# Why does the Underline function in JavaScript not working?

Tags: javascript, css

```js
function underline() {

  var text = document.getElementById("note_header").style.textDecoration;

  if (text == 'normal') {
    document.getElementById("note_header").style.textDecoration = 'Underline';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("note_header").style.textDecoration = 'normal';
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Underline" name="btn" onclick="underline()">
```

Comment: show your html and also include how you are calling the function

Comment: Down voter can you please add comment for down vote.

Comment: use if (text == '') instead of `if(text == 'normal')`

Comment: <input id="btn" type="button" value="Underline" name="btn" onclick="underline()">

Comment: I don't see any element with `note_header` as the ID, can you please include it as well?

Comment: note_header just represent the textarea where i type the text to be underline.

Comment: It works like this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/2hpxj58g/ (you would need to use `getComputedStyle()`, and the default is `none`, not `normal`)

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`normal` is not an accepted value for `text-decoration`. Use `none` instead.

```js
function underline(){
  var text = document.getElementById("note_header").style.textDecoration;
  
  if (text !== 'underline'){
    document.getElementById("note_header").style.textDecoration = 'underline';
  } else{
    document.getElementById("note_header").style.textDecoration = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="note_header"  rows="3" cols="15">
That's my note
</textarea><br/>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Underline" name="btn" onclick="underline()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function underline(){
  var text = document.getElementById("note_header").style.textDecoration;
  if (text == 'none'){
    document.getElementById("note_header").style.textDecoration = 'Underline';
  } else{
    document.getElementById("note_header").style.textDecoration = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="note_header" style="text-decoration:none;">This is anchor</a>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Underline" name="btn" onclick="underline()">
```